# Eldoc showing extra newline character in minibuffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Eldoc, which nicely shows documentation for elisp functions now takes 2 lines of the minibuffer. It is bothering me so much that I hit `C-M-c` (abort recursive edit) constantly to remove the documentation momentarily. Though, every time I type a character, it resizes the minibuffer to 1 line, and then to 2 lines to show the documentation (even though it only has 1 line to display).

If anyone ever had this issue, they'll know how annoying it is. Would anyone know a solution?

(Emacs 24, Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: This doesn't happen in 24.3.1, and I've certainly never noticed the issue in prior versions. Which specific version are you running?

Comment: @phils 24.2.1. I found out what is the problem (answer below), but I don't understand the why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that eldoc's text emphasizes some parts in bold and that those bold parts (in the font size you have selected) end up drawn a bit taller, thus exceeding (ever so slightly) the size of a single line.  The root problem is hence either a bug in Emacs that did not choose the bold font correctly, or a bug in your bold font which is taller than it should.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like the real solution is to let Emacs Dev know how annoying you feel this is: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  If it annoys you that much then it is likely that it annoys others too.  It would help most if Emacs Dev removes the annoyance in vanilla Emacs.  Especially if there is a simple fix and it is easy to describe the problem.

Comment: I agree that the minibuffer should generally only be one line of text.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I found out that the recent change to my default font size (from 10 to 9) had this effect. Can anyone explain? Is there some special font that then also has to be lowered to 9 or something?